# PHP: Provide a SOAP-Method called "echo"

Tags: php, soap, echo

i must provide a function via SOAP which is called "echo". I don't know how to do this because echo is already resevered by PHP. Is there any way?

BTW: I can't use rename_function or override_function. Pecl-Apd isn't available at the system.

Here is some code-stuff:

PHP:

```
$soap_server = new SoapServer('service.wsdl');
$soap_server->setClass('TestClass');

$soap_server->handle();
```

from the service.wsdl:

```
<message name="echo">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:echo"/>
  </message>

[...]

<portType name="MyService">
[...]
<operation name="echo">
      <input message="tns:echo"/>
      <output message="tns:echoResponse"/>
    </operation>
[...]
</portType>
<binding name="MyServicePortBinding" type="tns:MyService">
[...]
<operation name="echo">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:ping"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
[...]
</binding>
```

The SOAP-Client isn't under my control. I must implement the given wsdl-file. But in my class always "echo" get called not "ping" and results in the error message `PHP Fatal error:  Function 'echo' doesn't exist in <file-path-and-name>`.

My TestClass looks like this:

```
<?php

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

class TestClass {

  public function __construct()
  {

  }

  [...]

  public function ping($inputString)
  {
     return $inputString;
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: Can you give some background to the question - is this a study homework, for example? I am guessing that you want a SOAP method called `echo`, rather than redefining PHP core functions? :)

Comment: @halfer FYI I deleted my answer because neither of my approaches worked anyway :( - although you may also be right and I may have interpretted the question wrong.

Comment: @halfer yes sorry, I need a SOAP method called "echo". I think it doesn't matter how the function name is.

Comment: OK, well 'soap methods' are not actually programmatic functions or class methods - they are simply systems that are activated by XML conversations - you send an xml request via HTTP and get a response back in the same transaction. Have you googled the problem ("soap php" is a good start)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem using a Proxy Class:

```
class MySoapProxy
{
  public function __call($methodName, $args) {
    if($methodName == "echo") $methodName = "ping";
    $soapClass = new TestClass();
    $result = call_user_func_array(array($soapClass, $methodName),  $args[0]);
    return array($methodName . 'Result' => $result);
  }
}
```

My TestClass:

```
class TestClass {

  [...]

  public function ping($inputString)
  {
     return $inputString;
  }

}
```

And the SoapServer looks like this:

```
$soap_server = new SoapServer('myservice.wsdl');
$soap_server->setClass('MySoapProxy');

$soap_server->handle();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's totally doable. You create your class that will be a "Handler" for your requests, name your method anything you want, for example

public function myecho(){

}

Then you will have to create a wsdl file and that's where you will have an entry for "echo" operation that points to your "myecho" function.

It will look something like this in your wsdl file:

```
<operation name="echo">
            <soap:operation soapAction="/service/myecho" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" namespace="/service" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" namespace="/service" />
            </output>
        </operation>
```

You will need to create your own wsdl file by hand, this is a different topic.

Comment: okay, thats an good idea. i tried: `<operation name="echo">
      <soap:operation soapAction="asdfhlasdjkfhasdkjfh"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
` but i get always the following error: `PHP Fatal error:  Function 'echo' doesn't exist`

Comment: @virusbrain - again, we'll need to see the code you're using. Please edit your original question and add it at the end.

Comment: Great. Can we see the code for TestClass as well? I haven't used SoapServer, but expect that you need to implement TestClass too. Have you read [the docs](http://php.net/SoapServer)?

Comment: Yes, I've read the docs. I've added some snipets from the TestClass but I think this isn't required because the echo-Method is called and not the ping-Method. The mapping: Call 'ping' when 'echo' is called from the SoapClient must be done by the wsdl, I think.